# Piping out to "New-Items" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pipe

I'm trying to output to a file that is created on the fly, but I can't seem to get either to work. Here's that portion of my code-

```
New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name $InfoLog -Type File -Force
New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name $ErrorLog -Type File -Force
"Script started at: $DateStamp_${TimeStamp}" | $InfoLog
```

I've also tried just ">>" instead of the pipe. The script runs fine, it just doesn't pipe the output into the file. Instead it pipes it out to a a files called "0" in the directory the script ran from.

Comment: You need to format your code so that it's readable. Use 4 spaces before each line of code. Also, you need to be specific about what exactly isn't working (error messages are always helpful).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things.

First, `New-Item` outputs the item it creates. So unless you do something with the output objects, New-Item will output the new file items to the pipeline. So I think you might want to say:

```
New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name $InfoLog -Type File -Force | Out-Null
```

Second, since you're not specifying the path to the file you want to write to, PowerShell will assume the current location.

Finally, if you want to write output to a log file, you probably want to use `Out-File`. Perhaps something like this:

```
$infoLogPath = Join-Path $LogPath $InfoLog
"Script started at: $DateStamp_${TimeStamp}" | Out-File $infoLogPath
```

`Join-Path` combines the directory and filename into a fully-qualified path name.